# C++ How to overload the subscript operator and return a function

Tags: c++

This question is same as i post. but i not get a good answer and now i try to make it much clear. (i hope!!)

I have a list (vector) that will hold 'key/value' pairs. Example of key/value pair is "Pi = 3.14159" or "UserName = Bob". The 'Value's
can be string, bool, int, float, or doubles. I need functions
for each data type that i can add to the list, for example.

```
Foo f; f["Pi"].SetFloat(3.14159);          <--- Add float key/value
Foo f; float myFloat = f["Pi"].GetFloat(); <--- Get float value
          or
Foo f; f["UserName"].SetStr("Bob");        <-- Add string key/value
Foo f; const char * name = f["UserName"].GetStr(); < -- Get String.
```

I have much of the code now. BUT i do not know how to overload the subscript [].

```
Foo & operator[]( const char * pszKey ){
   *this->????
 }
```

The Foo & operator[]( const char * pszKey) should let me find the Key and inside the function should let me add key/value or return a value.
I do not know how to add key/value or return the value useing the
subscript operator. I hope someone can write a small code to help me understand and help me with is question??

This is some of my code i have now.

```
const char * va( const char * fmt, ... ) { // va = "VarArgs"
  // Format a value into a string.
 }

void Foo::SetString( const char * Key, const char * ) { // Private
   // Add 'key' and 'value' to a vector as a pair.
 }

const char * Foo::GetString( const char * key ) {  // Private
   // Look up 'key' from the vector and return the 'value'.
 }

...

const char * Foo::GetStr( const * Key ) {
  ...
 }
void Foo::SetStr( const char * Key, const int Value ) {
   SetStr( Key, va("%i", Value ));
 }

float Foo::GetFloat( const char * Key ) {
   return (float) atof( GetStr( Key ));
 }
void Foo::SetFloat( const char * Key ) {
  ....
 }  

void Foo::SetInt( .... ) ;
const int * Foo::GetInt(...);

void Foo::SetBool( ... ); 
const bool Foo::GetBool(...);
```

Comment: std::map of std::string to std::variant is what I would do

Comment: Why not return `std::variant<string, bool, int, float, double>`? `*this->????` ? You would return `Foo` object. Why a `&`? Does the object exist?

Answer (score 0):

The subscript operator should return whatever variant type you are using to store the float, int, string, etc.

And that variant type (`Foo`, is it?) should have assignment and conversion operators:

```
struct my_variant_type
{
  ...

  operator int   () const { return GetInt(); }
  operator float () const { return GetFloat(); }
  operator string() const { return GetStr(); }
  etc

  my_variant_type & operator = ( int n ) { SetInt( n ); return *this; }
  my_variant_type & operator = ( float f ) { SetFloat( f ); return *this; }
  my_variant_type & operator = ( const std::string & s ) { SetStr( s ); return *this; }
  etc
};
```

Now you can say things like:

```
float pi = my_collection["pi"];
my_collection["name"] = "Harry Potter";
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly why not just use `std::map<std::string, std::variant<...>>` and use `operator=` with variant constructor for assignment and `std::get<>` for getting value of proper type. Anyway, here's a wrapper around with requested interface that you proposed:

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct Foo {
    using Value = std::variant<
        std::string,
        bool,
        int,
        float,
        double>;
    std::map<std::string, Value> data;

    struct YourInterface {
        Value& v;
        float GetFloat() {
            return std::get<float>(v);
        }
        void SetFloat(float f) {
            v = Value(f);
        }
        void SetStr(std::string n) {
            v = Value(n);
        }
        std::string GetStr() {
            return std::get<std::string>(v);
        }
        // etc.
    };
    YourInterface operator[](const char *pszKey) {
        return FooInterface(data[pszKey]);
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f["UserName"].SetStr("Bob");
    float myFloat = f["Pi"].GetFloat();
    f["UserName"].SetStr("Bob");
    std::string name = f["UserName"].GetStr();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. i know know what 'FooInterface' is??

Comment: Most probably it should have been `YourInterface`